# jni native method freezes on file open

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

When the java code is at

```
 GraphJNIStuff.doMagic(); //my native method call
```

nothing happens...
..except that the program freezes

after "debuging" by placing return; (is there a better way?) in c code i found out that the problematic bit is

```
 FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
```

why??

I don't know what info would be helpful in this situation but if you need anything please say so

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the relative path instead of absolute. See if that works:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("./examplepath/file", "r");
```

Answer (score 3):

That should not cause any problems, assuming it's used correctly. Are you sure the file exists/you have permission to access it? Try verifying that fopen was successful.
IE:

```
...fp = fopen...
if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "File could not be opened\n");
    return -1;
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "File opened successfully\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fopen doesn't return it freezes during the run of the function

Comment: permissions are ok - i 777d that

Comment: ok i changed absolute path for a relative path an it stops freezing

Comment: I cant for some reason answer my own question. Someone please do it.